Select parent node from a javascript object
From a list like this
table:any[] = [
    {
      name: 'A1 - John Doe', 
      icon: 'user-name',
      bold: true,
      code: 'NY',
      open: false,
      items: [
        {
          name: 'D3_AIR_ASBJHABSJAS',
          icon: 'package',
          open: false,
          items: [
            { 
              name: 'Charge Type 1',
              open: false,
              items: [
                { 
                  name: 'Charge Type 1.1',
                  icon: 'departure-nofill',
                  date: '12/10/2024'
                },
                { name: 'Charge Type 1.2'},
                { name: 'Charge Type 1.3'},
                { name: 'Charge Type 1.4',
                  items: [
                    { name: 'Charge Type 2.1'},
                    { name: 'Charge Type 2.2'},
                    { name: 'Charge Type 2.3'},
                  ]
                },
              ]
            },
            { 
              name: 'Charge Type 2',
              open: false,
              items: [
                { name: 'Charge Type 2.1'},
                { name: 'Charge Type 2.2'},
                { name: 'Charge Type 2.3',
                  items: [
                    { name: 'Charge Type 2.1.1'},
                  ]
                },
              ]
            },
            { 
              name: 'Charge Type 3',
              items: [
                { name: 'Charge Type 3.1'},
              ]
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Hotel Beach Park',
          icon: 'departure-nofill',
          date: '12/10/2024'
        }

      ]
    },
    {name: '567', code: 'NYF',
      items: [
        { name: 'Charge Type 3.1'},
      ]
    },
  ];

how to select it's parent node by this child value { name: 'Charge Type 1.2'},
tried hasChildNodes(). But not working.
var item={ name: 'Charge Type 1.2'};
var parent=getParentElement(item)

I want to return like
{ 
              name: 'Charge Type 1',
              open: false,
              items: [
                { 
                  name: 'Charge Type 1.1',
                  icon: 'departure-nofill',
                  date: '12/10/2024'
                },
                { name: 'Charge Type 1.2'},
                { name: 'Charge Type 1.3'},
                { name: 'Charge Type 1.4',
                  items: [
                    { name: 'Charge Type 2.1'},
                    { name: 'Charge Type 2.2'},
                    { name: 'Charge Type 2.3'},
                  ]
                },
              ]
            }


You can find the element in the tree recursively.
Here is an example
function findParentElement(childElement) {
  const childName = childElement.name

  function recursiveSearch(items, parent) {
    for (let item of items) {
      if (item.name === childName) {
        return parent;
      }
      if (item.items) {
        const result = recursiveSearch(item.items, item);
        if (result) {
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  return recursiveSearch(table, null);
}

